# Pegar a extensão de um arquivo

Tags: php, arquivo

Olá, eu tentei usar o `pathinfo()` porem acho que eu não usei da forma correta, gostaria de saber como usar.

```
$arquivo_up = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];

$extensao = pathinfo($arquivo_up);
$extensao = $extensao['extension'];

if($extensao == "torrent")
{
}
```

Ele da esse erro

[image]

e a linha 2 é essa

```
$arquivo_up = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
```

Comment: Podes por um display do output de 'echo $arquivo_up'

Comment: Não é um erro em si. Está noticiando que a variável é nula, ou o $FILES[] não contém nada.
Geralmente aparece em momentos pré-checkout. Pode acontecer do form não enviar o arquivo, caso o enctype não esteja em multipart/form-data

Answer (score 12):

O teu código está muito próximo do que estas a tentar obter. Tenta assim:

```
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

A função [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) pode receber várias opções de acordo com as tuas necessidades:

- PATHINFO_DIRNAME
- PATHINFO_BASENAME
- PATHINFO_EXTENSION
- PATHINFO_FILENAME

Pode acontecer, não sei se é o teu caso, que o ficheiro não tenha extenção, nesse caso não irá devolver qualquer extensão.

Outra causa provável pode ser a tua configuração não estar correcta. Normalmente estes são os parâmetros que deverias usar (php.config)

```
file_uploads    "1"
upload_max_filesize     "2M"
post_max_size   "8M"
max_file_uploads    20
```

O upload_max_filesize deve estar de acordo com a tua necessidade. Caso estejas a fazer upload de ficheiros de maior tamanho deves ajustar.

Outra coisa que deves verificar, a tag form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action='...' method='post'>
```

Comment: Continua sem dar certo, mesmo colocando um torrent.

Comment: Podes actualizar a tua pergunta com o output de 'echo $arquivo_up'

Comment: Eu coloquei e não aparece nada, o código continua normalmente

Comment: Isso significa que provavelmente o teu array não contem o nome do ficheiro. Podes ver o output de var_dump($_FILES);

Comment: Apareceu isso aqui

array (size=0)
empty

Answer (score 0):

Já que seu `$_FILES` está vazio, eis uma *checklist* para *upload* de arquivos com PHP

No servidor:

1. Verifique em seu `php.ini` se as seguintes diretivas têm esses valores:

   `file_uploads = On`
   `post_max_size = 100M`
   `upload_max_filesize = 100M`

> Cuidado com erros comuns ao configurar a unidade de tamanho. Perceba acima que é `100M` e não `100MB`

2. Tenha certeza de que você está editando o `php.ini` certo. Após salvar as opções e reiniciar o servidor verifique através de um [phpinfo()](http://www.php.net/phpinfo) se os valores definidos são aqueles que você definiu

> Você pode precisar um arquivo `.htaccess` ou `.user.ini` caso você venha a utilizar um servidor compartilhado no qual você não teria acesso ao `php.ini

3. Garanta que seu diretório de arquivos temporários, definidio na diretiva `upload_tmp_dir` do `php.ini`, e o diretório no qual você vai gravar os arquivos enviados têm as devidas permissões de leitura e escrita definidas

> Tais diretórios não podem ter espaços como `/tmp/my uploads`

4. É bem raro, principalmente no seu caso com arquivos pequenos, mas um comentário, hoje extinto, no Manual do PHP, orientava que se tenha certeza de que haja espaço em disco suficiente para a operação

Quanto ao HTML:

1. Tenha certeza de que seu formulário tenha o atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.
2. Requisições GET não suportam uploads com `multipart/form-data`, então seus formulários devem ser definidos com `method="POST"`

> Tal atributo deve estar obrigatoriamente na(s) tag(s) `<form>` e envolto por aspas e não *backticks* que alguns editores acabam convertendo acidentalmente.

3. Tenha certeza de que você não tenha dois ou mais `<input type="file" />` com mesmo valor para o atributo `name`.  Se você precisar de upload múltiplo, adicione um par de colchetes ao final do nome:

   ```
   <input type="file" name="files[]">
   <input type="file" name="files[]">
   ```

> Apesar de óbvio, o atributo `name` deve estar presente em todos os campos que deverão ser processados

4. Lembre-se de fechar todas as tags `<form>` da sua página com a contraparte `</form>`
5. Garanta que você não esteja aninhando formulários:

   ```
   <form><form></form></form>
   ```
6. E nem sobrepondo tags:

   ```
   <div><form></div></form>
   ```
7. Por último mas não menos importante, verifique se não há nenhum JavaScript desabilitando o envio do formulário ou removendo o(s) elemento(s) `<input type="file">`

No que tange o usuário final:

1. Tenha certeza de que o arquivo sendo enviado não possua caracteres não alfa-numéricos nele
2. Caso seja upload "assíncrono", JavaScript deve, obviamente estar habilitado

E quanto ao programador?

Bom, você está recebendo um E_NOTICE de índice não definido então você deve checar se tal índice existe.

Dê um [var_dump()](http://www.php.net/var_dump) / [print_r()](http://www.php.net/print_r) em $_FILES e veja a estrutura do superglobal. Ela é REALMENTE unidimensional?

Bastante comum em uploads múltiplos, de repente o que você usa como `$_FILES['arquivo']['name']` pode ter um índice numérico a mais

Resolvido o caso, para obter a extensão do arquivo você pode fazer com [pathinfo()](http://www.php.net/pathinfo), como já está fazendo, mas adicione a constante pré-definida PATHINFO_EXTENSION como já sugerido.

Apenas atente que caso o *path* a ser analisado termine com um ponto (o que pra todos os efeitos é um arquivo sem uma extensão válida), [pathinfo()](http://www.php.net/pathinfo) retornará uma string vazia, mas caso o arquivo não tenha extensão alguma ele vai retornar NULL.

Então tome cuidado ;)

Outra opção seria com manipulamento simples de strings:

```
$ext = ltrim( substr( __FILE__, strrpos( __FILE__, '.' ) ), '.' );
```

Se houver um ponto na string, retorna o valor após ele, de trás pra frente.

Se não houver, retorna a própria string, já que [strrpos()](http://www.php.net/strrpos) vai falhar e o *cast* automático do PHP fará [substr()](http://www.php.net/substr) considerar essa "falha" como zero e isso faz a substring iniciar desde o começo dela.