# Duvida sobre função PHP 'end'

Tags: php

A minha dúvida está na `$extensao`, onde contém um parenteses no início e no fim. Qual o motivo dele estar ali?

```
$extensao = ( end ( explode ('.', $_FILES [ "img" ][ "name"] ) ) ) ;

$imagem = md5 ( uniqid ( $_FILES [ "img" ][ "name" ] ) ).'.'.$extensao ;

move_uploaded_file ( $_FILES [ "img" ][ "tmp_name" ], "upload/".$imagem ) ;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exatamente assim, os parenteses no início e no fim **não fazem nada!**

```
$extensao = ( end ( explode ('.', $_FILES [ "img" ][ "name"] ) ) ) ;
 -----------^                                                    ^----
```

O pequeno problema desse código é que a partir do php5.3 ele gera um Strict Standards que basicamente é um warning, a mensagem é a seguinte:

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in

Agora sim falando do parenteses que faz a diferença, para forar o retorno(valor) do `explode()` virar um refêrencia adicione os parenteses:

```
$extensao =  end ( ( explode ('.', $_FILES [ "img" ][ "name"] ) ) )  ;
-------------------^                                            ^----
```

Faça o teste exibindo todos os erros dessa maneira:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$extensao =  end( (explode ('.', 'arquivo.ext' ) ) );
$extensao =  end(explode ('.', 'arquivo.ext' )) ;
```

---

### Update PHP7

Agora no PHP7, mesmo com esses parenteses adicionais será gerado um warning ou seja trate warnings ou esses tipos de gambiarras, nesse caso é so criar uma variáve adicional e passar para a função.

[Parentheses around function parameters no longer affect behaviour](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.parentheses)

---

### Como pegar a extensão de um arquivo

A mais correta forma de pegar a extensão é usar `pathinfo()` como mostra [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/61446/91).

<sub>*Obs tentei fazer um exemplo no ideone, phpfidle e 3v4l.org, parece que diretiva que habilita todos os erros está desligada.</sub>

Comment: Ok, thannks....

Comment: +1 pelo `pathinfo`. Pra deixar a treta orientada a objeto eu faria `$file = new SplFileObject($_FILES [ "img" ][ "name"]);`

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, não conheço isso, vou olhar depois. Não é pq resolve que vc deve solucionar o problema achando que tudo é manipulação de texto/string. Valeu a dica :D