# Erro em uma library do Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho a library a seguir no codeigniter:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Breadcrumb {

private $breadcrumbs = array();
private $separator = '  >  ';
private $start = '<div id="breadcrumb">';
private $end = '</div>';

public function __construct($params = array()){
    if (count($params) > 0){
        $this->initialize($params);
    }
}

private function initialize($params = array()){
    if (count($params) > 0){
        foreach ($params as $key => $val){
            if (isset($this->{'_' . $key})){
                $this->{'_' . $key} = $val;
            }
        }
    }
}

function add($title, $href){  
    if (!$title OR !$href) return;
    $this->breadcrumbs[] = array('title' => $title, 'href' => $href);
}

function output(){
    if ($this->breadcrumbs) {
        $output = $this->start;
        foreach ($this->breadcrumbs as $key => $crumb) {
            if ($key){
                $output .= $this->separator;
            }

            if (end(array_keys($this->breadcrumbs)) == $key) {
                $output .= '<span>' . $crumb['title'] . '</span>';   
            }
            else {
                $output .= '<a href="' . $crumb['href'] . '">' . $crumb['title'] . '</a>';
            }
        }

        return $output . $this->end . PHP_EOL;
    }
    return '';
}
}
```

No controller faço a inserção das breadcrumbs:

```
public function index(){
    $this->breadcrumb->add('Home', base_url());
    $this->breadcrumb->add('Tutorials', base_url().'tutorials');  
    $this->breadcrumb->add('Spring Tutorial', base_url().'tutorials/spring-tutorials');
    $this->dados['breadcrumb']  =   $this->breadcrumb->output();
    $this->dados['conteudo']    =   'layouts/moderador/painel_controle_view';
    $this->load->view('layouts/layout_master',$this->dados);
}
```

E na view faço a exibição:

```
<div id="conteudo" class="container principal">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>PAINEL DE CONTROLE</p>
                <p><?= (!empty($breadcrumb)?$breadcrumb:''); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Quando executo está aparecendo a seguinte mensagem:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Runtime Notice
>
> Message: Only variables should be passed by reference
>
> Filename: libraries/Breadcrumb.php
>
> Line Number: 37
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: D:\wamp\www\PortalCompras\application\libraries\Breadcrumb.php
>   Line: 37 Function: _error_handler
>
> File:
>   D:\wamp\www\PortalCompras\application\controllers\moderador\Painel_controle.php
>   Line: 13 Function: output
>
> File: D:\wamp\www\PortalCompras\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

Não consegui identificar o erro.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na linha:

```
if (end(array_keys($this->breadcrumbs)) == $key) {
```

A função [`end()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) segundo a documentação somente aceita referências como argumento, ou seja, apenas variáveis do retorno de método ou função não valem. Veja a assinatura da função:

> mixed end ( array &$array )

Aquele `&` significa que o argumento deve ser uma variável e não um valor, isso acontece com alguma frequência.

Para resolver é bem simples atribua o resultado de [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) em uma nova variável e depois passe ela para `end()`:

```
$keys = array_keys($this->breadcrumbs);
if(end($keys) == $key){
```

**Relacionada:**

[Duvida sobre função PHP 'end'](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/83798/91)

Comment: A sua dica solucionou meu problema. Fiz exatamente como indicou e a mensagem de erro desapareceu.